# Rails ActiveRecord combining result of multiple queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Model:

```
player
    belongs_to :current_club
    belongs_to :parent_club
    has_many :ratings

rating
    belongs_to :player
```

Basic Schema:

```
create_table "clubs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "league_id"
    t.string  "club_name"
end

create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "player_id"
    t.string  "player_name"
    t.integer "current_club_id"
    t.integer "parent_club_id"
end

create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "player_id"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.date    "date"
end
```

I want to get the most recent rating for every player who doesn't work at a particular current_club and list players in descending order of that latest rating.

For getting the latest rating information of all players and listing in descending order, the following works:

```
@ratings = Rating.select([:player_id, :rating, :date, 'MAX(date)']).order('rating desc').group(:player_id)
```

And for getting the information of all players who are not at a particular current_club, the following works:

```
@players = Player.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50).includes(:current_club).where.not(current_club_id: 101121)
```

I just can't work out how to combine the two so that it gets the most recent rating for all players in descending order and the player information for all players who aren't at current_club 101121. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the order in relationship definition:

```
player
    belongs_to :current_club
    belongs_to :parent_club
    has_many :ratings, -> { order(rating: :desc) }
```

Now you can simply call:

```
@players = Player.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50).includes(:current_club, :ratings).where.not(current_club_id: 101121)
```

Comment: That won't work. Players have multiple ratings that can either go up or down. I want to get the most recent rating and sort that in descending order. With what you've suggested, it'll have multiple ratings by each player instead of the latest one.